# Using Mover.io to migrate folders from one document library to another on separate site

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, migration

I am wondering if I can use mover.io to move folders from one document library to another, on different sites?

Outline structure;
***Sharepoint Online Domain***
'- **Team site 1**
-- Document Library 1
--- Folder A (To move to Team site 2)
--- Folder B
'- **Team site 2**
-- Document Library 2
--- Folder A (moved from Team site 1)

I am looking at mover.io for this due to the quantity and size of documents involved.  It would be a ontime migration.

Is it possible to use Mover.io in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could use mover to move foldes from one document library to another between differernt sites.

Besides, SharePoint online has built-in functions to move/copy folders/files. I would sugeest you use that. Please refer to this article for more:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/move-or-copy-files-in-sharepoint-00e2f483-4df3-46be-a861-1f5f0c1a87bc

Comment: Thanks.  I was well aware of the built-in function but I'm thinking the quantity to move will exceed the microsoft limits and i run risk of violating their fair use policy!  thanks for confirming as to mover.io though.